# expected expression before "hashLink"

Tags: c, struct

I'm getting an error I cannot figure out.  I'm trying to define an instance of a struct.  I do this several times in the code, and I get the same error every time.  I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Struct Definition:

```
 struct hashLink {
      KeyType key; /*the key is what you use to look up a hashLink*/
      ValueType value; /*the value stored with the hashLink, a pointer to int in the case of concordance*/
      struct hashLink * next; /*notice how these are like linked list nodes*/
};
typedef struct hashLink hashLink;
```

Call in the code (one example):

```
hashLink *temp = malloc(sizeof hashLink);
hashLink *temp2 = malloc(sizeof hashLink);
```

precise error I get is:

```
 C:\Users\Marshall\C\CS261\hashMap.c||In function '_freeMap':|
 C:\Users\Marshall\C\CS261\hashMap.c|73|error: expected expression before 'hashLink'|
 C:\Users\Marshall\C\CS261\hashMap.c|74|error: expected expression before 'hashLink'|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof hashLink` ---> `sizeof(hashLink)`

When used with types, the operator `sizeof` requires parentheses.

Comment: +1 I would not recommend using it like that anyway. Rather, use `sizeof (*temp)`. Its a personal preference thing I know. Dunno if his was the OP's problem, but it is certainly probable.

Comment: @WhozCraig The funny thing is that then it wouldn't need parentheses: "sizeof *temp" would be fine.

Comment: Of course, but *with* them it always works. Without them... well... [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434988/expected-expression-before-hashlink/18435052#18435052) =P

Comment: @WhozCraig: the link is to this answer...did you have another in mind.  I agree 100% with the sentiment '`sizeof(x)` works correctly for all x' and I always use parentheses.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That was the intent (ok, admittedly somewhat stealth sarcasm. Probably inappropriate for SO but I couldn't resist) It really is very simple direct answer, though.